# How do you generate an Image in a Windows Phone Scheduled Agent?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I need to generate an imaged based on data returned from a WebService call within a PeriodicTask in a Windows Phone app (Mango+).
I've seen a few ways of doing it in the main app but nothing that seems to work from a Scheduled Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  If you're in a background agent, memory is precious.  The libraries you load count against your allocation limit, too, so you have less than the advertised amount.

Do you have a base image that you're modifying?  If so, avoid creating UI elements and try to work with a WriteableBitmap.  There is a library (yes, memory, but it's incredibly useful) that provides useful methods for working with such images called [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).

If you're generating simple images from scratch, going the UserControl route is workable too.

Comment: A base image would work, I'll take a look at WriteableBitmapEx. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's going to work. I've been traveling so I haven't pulled all the code together yet

Answer (score 1):

Try this guide I've described on my blog:
http://suchan.cz/?p=110

Basically you have to create your own UserControl and then render it into image and save it either as jpg, without transparency, or as transparent png. Also make sure you use as low memory as you can in the Backgroud Agent, if you use more than 6MB in WP7 or 11MB in WP8, your periodic task will be killed without notice.

Answer (score 1):

I use a utility called ImageTools to [render a PNG from a user control](http://notebookheavy.com/2011/12/06/microsoft-style-dynamic-tiles-for-windows-phone-mango/) (note, this is not my blog).  I created a shared library, with references to ImageTools, ImageTools.IO.Png, and ImageTools.Utils.  The shared library does all the heavy lifting.  Then my background agent project references the shared library project, and in the ScheduledAgent.OnInvoke it calls into the shared library to do the work.  I am on Windows Phone 8 but it seems to work very well.

Comment: Have you uploaded your app to the marketplace/store yet? There are a lot of APIs Scheduled Agents can't use

Comment: Yes I have - it passed certification (twice) so I assume everything is OK.